# Ubuntu Software Installation

Tags: software-installation

[image]

Hi, I am trying to install uget and I get this error message "This requires installing packages from unathenticated sources" and there are only two options. Ok and Repair, and even if i click both their is nothing happening. It keeps on popping up. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Use the commands in my answer. If there is an error message, add the error messages by [edit]ing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the repository and re-add it again:

1. Remove the repository

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
   sudo ppa-purge ppa:plushuang-tw/uget-stable
   ```
2. Add the repository

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:plushuang-tw/uget-stable
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Install `uget`

   ```
   sudo apt install uget
   ```